# jquery form not working as expected. ajaxForm is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-forms-plugin, ajaxform

I am trying to use jquery form but it sais in the concole ajaxForm is not a function.
The jquery.form.js is properly included and the code is in a document ready function...

This is the script:

```
$("#apply-form").ajaxForm({

                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $("#progress").show();
                    //clear everything
                    $("#bar").width('0%');
                    $("#message").html("");
                    $("#percent").html("0%");
                },
                uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete)
                {
                    $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
                    $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');

                },
                success: function()
                {
                    $("#bar").width('100%');
                    $("#percent").html('100%');

                },
                complete: function(response)
                {
                    $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    $("#message").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");

                }
            });
```

And here is the HTML form

```
<form id="apply-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">


    <table>
                <tr><td>CV:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="cover">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Cover Letter:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="curriculum">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div id="progress">
                            <div id="bar"></div>
                            <div id="percent">0%</div >
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div id="message"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

i am making the site in codeigniter and i have a header template that is included o every page. and in the head section i am including all my scripts in this order:

```
<script src="/jobs/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jobs/public/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="/jobs/public/js/javascript.js"></script>
<link href="/jobs/public/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/jobs/public/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/jobs/public/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
```

I am also using jQuery UI. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Is jQuery itself also loaded properly?
Can you make a `jsfiddle` with your HTML also?

Comment: yep. and it is loaded before jquery form

Comment: any other error in your console

Comment: Does `$().ajaxForm` in your browser's inspector return the `ajaxForm function?

Comment: no any other errors. just this one

Comment: $().ajaxForm returns undefined...

Comment: `ajaxForm` library might not be loaded when document gets ready, you can find this in chromes network tab or see the inspector's console.

Comment: Could you show us where and how you load the scripts?

Comment: in firebug at the script section the jquery.form.js appears as included

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are loading jQuery twice.  The second loading of jQuery overrides the first and clobbers any plugins.

```
<script src="/jobs/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jobs/public/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
...
<script src="/jobs/public/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

It is this second `jquery-1.9.1` that is not getting `.ajaxForm`. Use one or the other.

Add the form jquery to the bottom of the scripts

Comment: thanks man. I didn't realise i included it twice...the second one was from jQuery UI :)

Comment: you post just saved me a whole day wasted, double loading of jquery detected. thanks

Answer (score 12):

Use this and work is done

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.3.0/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha384-qlmct0AOBiA2VPZkMY3+2WqkHtIQ9lSdAsAn5RUJD/3vA5MKDgSGcdmIv4ycVxyn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Does not work anymore. Use this instead: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.3.0/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha384-qlmct0AOBiA2VPZkMY3+2WqkHtIQ9lSdAsAn5RUJD/3vA5MKDgSGcdmIv4ycVxyn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 3):

i designed a good uploader just like this :

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>
```

and worked complete and used ajax just like this :

```
$('form').ajaxForm
    ({

    beforeSend: function() 
    {
    var percentVal = '20%';
    prog.css("width",percentVal);

    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
    {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';

    prog.css("width",percentVal);
    darsad.html(percentVal + ' uploading .');
    //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
    },
    success: function() 
    {
    var percentVal = '100%';

    darsad.html(percentVal + ' uploaded success.');
    prog.css("width",percentVal);

    },
    complete: function(xhr) 
    {
    //status.html(xhr.responseText);
    darsad.html(percentVal + ' uploaded complete.');
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxForm is not a function` basically means, either the function does not exist or the function has problems somewhere.

I fixed this by sort back the plugin load/ path and js file. In my case, the function can't be called because the order is wrong.